Jacobi Elliptic Functions
I'm not sure if the answer should go in this forum or in the Mathematica forum, but I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$ \left( \frac{d u}{d \phi} \right)^{2} = Q u^{3} + P u^{2} + c $$
where $Q$, $P$ and $c$ are positive constants. My idea is to follow the procedure of this paper where they solve the differential equation (equation 3.12)
$$ \left( \frac{du}{d \phi} \right)^{2} = 2 M u^{3} - u^{2} + \frac{2 M}{h^{2}} u + C $$
and rewrite it as
$$ \left( \frac{du}{d \phi} \right)^{2} = 2 M ( u - \alpha ) ( u - \beta) ( u - \gamma) $$
forming the system of equations (equation 3.14)
$$ \alpha + \beta + \gamma = \frac{1}{M} $$
$$ \beta \gamma + \gamma \alpha + \alpha \beta = \frac{1}{h^{2}}$$
$$ \alpha \beta \gamma = - \frac{C}{2 M} $$
Then, they get as a result (equation 3.15)
$$ u = A + \frac{B}{\cosh^{2} (\omega \phi)} $$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants given in the article (equations 3.16 and 3.17). In my case, I rewrote the initial equation as:
$$ \left( \frac{d u}{ d \phi} \right)^{2} = Q \left( u^{3} + \frac{P}{Q} u^{2} + \frac{c}{Q} \right) = Q (u - \alpha) (u - \beta) (u - \gamma) $$
from which, by expanding and comparing, I get:
$$ \alpha + \beta + \gamma = - \frac{P}{Q} $$
$$ \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma + \alpha \beta = 0 $$
$$ \alpha \beta \gamma = - \frac{C}{Q} $$
So, we can take $\alpha > \beta \geq u \geq \gamma > 0$. So,
$$ \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{ Q (u - \alpha) (u - \beta) (u - \gamma) }} = \int \phi $$
However, my problem here is that I don't know how to take the correct roots from the system of equations that allow me to write the solution in terms of Jacobi elliptic functions. The roots I get are very extensive. For example, using Mathematica some that I got are:

Could anyone guide me or give me some suggestions? Sorry if the question was not posted here. Thanks in advance!

@peterag Thanks for the observation!

I strongly suggest to not use Cardano's formula.
The cubic being $$ Q u^{3} + P u^{2} + c=0$$ the discriminant is
$$\Delta= -c \left(27\, c\, Q^2+4 P^3\right)$$ which is negative. So, there is only one real root, given by
$$u_1=-\frac{P}{3 Q}\left(1+2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{27\, c\, Q^2}{2 P^3}+1\right)\right)\right)$$ You have the two other roots (complex conjugate) by deflation of the cubic.

Thank you very much for your reply. But I would like to know if the procedure I followed afterwards is correct. I wrote:
$$ \left( \frac{d u}{d \phi} \right)^{2} = Q (u-u_{1}) (u^{2} + A u_{1} + B) $$
where:
$$ A = u_{1} + \frac{P}{Q}, \ \ \ B = \left( u_{1} + \frac{P}{Q} \right) u_{1}  $$
So,
$$ \frac{d u}{\sqrt{ Q (u - u_{1}) (u^{2} + A u_{1} + B) }} = d \phi $$
However, when I solve I get a complex expression that is not what I expected (I am looking for a real solution to the differential equation). Is it possible that I have an error?
